# Fixing NoSuchMethodException with Kotlin Reflection on Private Functions

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to invoke a private Kotlin function that takes a primitive int and a String as parameters using reflection, but I am running into a NoSuchMethodException. Below is the code for the class containing the private function and the test function where I am trying to invoke it:

```
class DataKey {
    private fun test22(num: Int, str: String): Int {
        // Function implementation
        return 1
    }
}
```

Here is the test function where I'm trying to invoke test22:

```
class DataKeyTest {
    private val dataKey = DataKey()

    @Test
    fun `INITK test`() = runBlocking {
        val result = UnitTestReflectionHelper.invokePrivate(dataKey, "test22", 1, "Hello") as Int
        Assert.assertEquals(result, 1)
    }
}
```

The UnitTestReflectionHelper class is defined as follows:

```
class UnitTestReflectionHelper {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T> invokePrivate(instance: T, methodName: String, vararg params: Any?): Any? {
            val method = T::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *params.map { it?.javaClass }.toTypedArray())
            method.isAccessible = true
            return method.invoke(instance, *params)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: co.service.provider.DataMada.test22(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)**

It seems like the issue is related to how Kotlin automatically boxes primitive types and how Java reflection requires explicit type matching. How can I modify my invokePrivate method to handle this type mismatch and correctly invoke the test22 method?

Comment: Looks like the order of the arguments is swapped (compare the method declaration and the error message)?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the values you passed are boxed. This is not Kotlin's fault. This is because you are passing them to an `Any?` parameter. The same thing would have happened in Java if you passed a `1` to an `Object` parameter.

You can try to "unbox" `it::class` by using [`javaPrimitiveType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-primitive-type.html) on its `KClass`:

```
val method = T::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *params.map {
    if (it == null) null else it::class.javaPrimitiveType ?: it.javaClass
}.toTypedArray())
```

That said, there are still problems with this design.

- This will unbox *every* parameter type that can be unboxed, making you unable to call methods that actually expect the boxed `Integer` type.
- You cannot get `::class`, or `.javaClass` for that matter, from `null`. This means you cannot pass `null` to any parameter.

To solve these problems, you should ask the caller to include the type of the parameter too. For example, you can take a series of `Pair<Class<*>, Any?>`

```
inline fun <reified T> invokePrivate(instance: T, methodName: String, vararg typesAndParams: Pair<Class<*>, Any?>): Any? {
    val (types, params) = typesAndParams.unzip()
    val method = T::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *types.toTypedArray())
    method.isAccessible = true
    return method.invoke(instance, *params.toTypedArray())
}
```

Usage:

```
val x = invokePrivate(dataKey, "test22",
    Integer.TYPE to 1,
    String::class.java to "Hello"
) as Int
```

Note that I'm using the field `java.lang.Integer.TYPE` here to write what would have been `int.class` in Java.